# How to Fill Parent with Dynamic Left Center Right DIVs?

Tags: html, css

EDIT:

Per Mat's suggestion below, I fiddled with jsFiddle and came up with the "real" problem.

Positioning content absolutely within the center DIV doesn't produce the required results:

http://jsfiddle.net/yxFQK/22/

In order to position children absolutely, the parent needs to be relative, right?  But that messes up the nice left/center/right layout:

http://jsfiddle.net/yxFQK/23/

Any ideas?  Thank you in advance.

---

ORIGINAL POST:

We want to have a fixed-width parent DIV with three dynamic-width children DIVs:

The left and right DIVs should size based on content.  The center DIV should fill the space between the left and right DIVs:

```
[[Left][        Center        ][Right]]
```

(or)

```
[[Big Left][    Center    ][Big Right]]
```

The center DIV should scroll overflow content (so we can't use overflow: hidden).

Also, we would like to change the parent DIV size (using CSS media queries), and have everything continue to fill in nicely:

```
[[Left][    Center    ][Right]]

[[Big Left][Center][Big Right]]

[[Left][              Center              ][Right]]

[[Big Left][          Center          ][Big Right]]
```

Any ideas?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on your answer so I'm submitting as an answer. Is this what you're looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/yxFQK/

Remember it's always easier to make a jsfiddle rather than try to explain visually/conceptually. If you frame the problem well it's easier for people to help you out.

Comment: You helped me frame the problem even better.  Thank you.  See my edits above.

Comment: Once you position an element absolutely you remove it from the flow of the document. So as far as I know that won't work with your idea of having the center div taken up the remaining space of the other two. Your best bet is to use floats.

As far as your other question goes: if you want to position children absolutely relative to their parent (ie 5px left of the left edge of the parent) then yes, the parent needs position: relative.